# Move Grouped Object using max script

Tags: 3dsmax

I am new to max and problem that i am facing is I have objects that are grouped togother there are 3 objects a box , a frame surrounding the box which has UV map and some rivets like objects on the frame. and name this group as storage When I try to move the grouped object using max script all the objects inside the group moves move individually rather than moving as a whole like a whole. Is there any other possible solution to do this or a method though which i can achieve the same.
[image]

Maxscript:

```
select $Storage
maxOps.cloneNodes (selection as array) cloneType:#instance newNodes:&nnl #nodialog
select nnl
nnl.pos =  [1,2,1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you clone and create new Nodes, they are ungrouped. If you use a group command to group nnl before you move them, you should be okay.

Comment: Can you please give an example or maybe link to a resource?